# Spyder failed to render latex when rendering a Sympy matrix

Tags: python, sympy, spyder

Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)
Python 4.0.0
Spyder updated today.
Running on a Mac iBook OS 10.10.1

```
>>> M = Matrix([[1, 0, 1, 3], [2, 3, 4, 7], [-1, -3, -3, -4]])
>>> M
```

produces the following error in the Spyder Internal Console:

```
>>> /Users/webe077/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nbformat/current.py:19: UserWarning: nbformat.current is deprecated.

- use nbformat for read/write/validate public API
- use nbformat.vX directly to composing notebooks of a particular version

  """)
ERROR:root:Failed to render latex: '$$\left ( \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 3\\0 & 1 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right], \quad \left [ 0, \quad 1\right ]\right )$$'
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "\right" (at char 14), (line:1, col:15)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/webe077/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 2333, in parse...
```

The example works fine in the Sympy web tool

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue recently, and it was solved on this [topic](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10264) by moorepants.

To sum up, you have to install the `dvipng` library on your computer so `sympy` does not rely on `matplotlib` to render latex matrices, which is not working.
I have installed `miktex` which includes `dvipng`, you can find another one if you want. 
Then, restart spyder and display the matrix. A window shows up, warning you that an external package is loaded. Click on "ok" and it should work.

Comment: If you don't want to install a latex interpreter, then you can do this: `init_printing(use_latex='matplotlib')`.  This will print the matrices as ascii.  Not exactly pretty, but at least works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have latex installed try

```
init_printing(use_latex=True)
```

instead of

```
init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
```